# API Graph Instagram:Get comments on media returns Error:400 The requested resource does not exist

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-graph-api

Recently I have issue that I don't understand the reason why this behavior.
When I use API to get comments on Media on Instagram_business_account
https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/media_id/comments?access_token=access_token&fields=id,timestamp,media{id,permalink},text,username,replies.limit(50){id,timestamp,text,username}&limit=50

some of them gives me as response:
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#24) The requested resource does not exist",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 24,
    "fbtrace_id": "GjEetUUnrND
"
  }
}
However the others are ok, no error,it gives me  the result attempted.
It is on the same instagram_business_account.

Does someone have faced to the same issue? and why this behavior and how to avoid it?
IS it a bug from facebook? I have already asked it in the facebook developper community but i don't have yet any replies.
If someone have an idea please

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Check that you're not duplicating setDefaultAccessToken or another $fb-> function. I had a duplicate function call and it gave me the same issue

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand exactly what you mean, for me I use token page so it is unique for each page_id facebook (instagram_business_account), As I said for another media of the same instagram_business_account, it gives me the result attempted without error, do you have any idea? how did you do to avoid the error thanks a lot